# Reactive pattern with Cook XML-RPC.NET design ideas

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, system.reactive, xml-rpc

I am trying to combine [possibly async] calls from XML-RPC.NET with Reactive Programming. I am new to Rx and only slowly beginning to understand how to take advantage of it. I am also fairly to XML-RPC.NET. I understand some of the inner workings, yet might be unaware of some of it "abilities."

In my code, I subscribe to request from an HTTP server as below:

```
var publisher = this.httpServer
    .TakeUntil(Observable.Create<object>(observer => token.Register(() => observer.OnNext(null))))
    .Where(ctx => ctx.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    .Subscribe(ctx =>               
        {
            ctx.Request.InputStream.ReadBytes(ctx.Request.ContentLength)
                .Subscribe(bts =>
                    {   
                        // Read Xml from the network
                        string Xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bts);
```

I want to use XML-RPC.NET to parse this XML message. How do I do this? The library operates with objects such as XmlRpcStruct.

If you have experience with such things, please suggest a design.

Comment: Could you please post all of the interfaces that we would need to be able to compile your code? i.e. what is `this.httpServer` & `token.Register`?

Comment: You also seem to be mixing OOP and functional styles. That's often hard to get right. You might need to provide the interface for `this` too.

Comment: Thank you for reading my post.
Token is the cancellation token. There is nothing to compile. I am looking for design suggestions. It is architecture, not coding question. At this time, I am considering: defining data contracts for deserialization and a state name service to process data received by the server. i don't fully like either.

Comment: Please don't tell me there is nothing to compile. I like to test my designs by running the code. I generally do not answer unless my code runs. A lot of people here are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your time, anyway. Unfortunately, I will have to try to figure this out without you. Appreciate your help.